# how to force delphi compiler to allocate memory for unused variables

Tags: delphi, variables, memory, allocation

I realized (the hard way, an hour of debugging) that my Delphi 2010 compiler with optimization off (and record alignment of 1 byte) does not allocate memory for unused variables. If they are defined like:

```
var x,y,z:longint; a1,a2,a3:whatever;
```

and y gets unused (actually, i removed a form from the project temporarily, which references that variable exclusively), then z is assigned the address of x+4. Nice except that i have a lot of code which will now mix z with a1. Can this be controlled by some switch? Thank you.

Comment: This is not possible. Please include a [mcve] that demonstrates *code that will mix z with a1* if you don't use `y`.

Comment: Whatever you're doing to rely on consistent address-offset assignment is fragile and ill-conceived. State your real problem about what you're trying to do and get a much more readable and maintainable program.

Comment: Thx all. 1) my verifiable examples are in inline assembler, and surely byte pointer increment in pascal would produce the same effect, but if there are no switches to force the allocation then it doesn't matter; 2) ill-conceived by your standards maybe, but i hate to prefix record members so i pass a pointer to the 1st var in a row to some of my procedures; this habit is neither rage nor fetish; simply, less words in my code, more readable and maintainable it is to me, that's how my brain works; there is no such thing as a "real problem"

Comment: Don't declare variables when using asm. Use pure asm and reserve the stack space yourself.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Why? Using the compiler to reserve the stack and name the variables within the asm code is less error prone, much more readable, and more maintainable (if you change one variable, you don't need to recompute all stack offsets).

Comment: @arnaud In reality you typically want to avoid memory and will optimise variables to registers. Usually you'll want to try to better the compiler. If you deny yourself the opportunity to enregistrer that will handicap you.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Of course, but here we were talking about the stack-allocated variables, not registers. Looking at http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf info, registers may not be much faster than local stack on some CPU (especially under x86) and for some opcodes, due to how micro-ops translation and execution in modern Intel/AMD chips. So we all know that we need profiling on actual HW. And you may very well declare some local variables, but don't use them but registers - this is what some ABIs do for parameters: reserve the space on stack, even if not used.

Answer (score 4):

This won't work. The compiler will optimize all unused variables.

What you can do is to define a packed record, as such:

```
type
  TMyData = packed record
    x,y,z: longing;
    a1,a2,a3: whatever;
  end;
```

Then the allocated `TMyData` will always be allocated as one, including all internal variables, even if they are not used in your code.

For temporary variables allocated on the stack, you may use:

```
function DoSomething();
var loc: packed record
      x,y,z: longing;
      a1,a2,a3: whatever;
    end;
begin
  loc.x := 10;
  ...
```

Comment: Thank you for bothering to post the answer. I'm aware of this possibility (along with the other one, and that is to write dummy lines of code mentioning relevant variables) and was just wondering if there is a compiler directive or some IDE setting.

Comment: @miodrag This is but one possibility. Others are using an array, or controlling the stack allocation yourself (as per David's comment). However,  all of these possibilities are pure speculation because ***you can't be bothered*** to post a MCVE demonstrating what you're trying achieve.

Comment: @Craig i wanted "LEA EBX,x; MOV [EBX+4],EAX" not to spoil my z variable, but y. the question was not how to do it (i'm sure there are infinite ways), but if it is achievable with a compiler switch, without altering the code. sorry i did not point this out better.